# asp.net application start fire multiple times

Tags: asp.net, timer, application-start

I have an ASP.NET 4 application written in c# in visual studio 2010.
I start a timer in application_start in Global.asax and I want it to start once but after logging application behavior I have noticed that application_start fires multiple times. Whenever there are no requests on the website for a while, application_start would fire on next request.
I am not doing any file operations and not modifying web.config file.
Is there a way to prevent this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a specified idle time IIS will shutdown application pool worker process. This value is set in advanced settings of application pool- Idle time-out (minutes)

After process is shutdown next request causes application start.